# Two gender switches in one Posuk "וַיְהִי בְשָׁלֵם סֻכּוֹ וּמְעוֹנָתוֹ בְצִיּוֹן"

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, tehilim-psalms, gender

> וַיְהִי בְשָׁלֵם סֻכּוֹ וּמְעוֹנָתוֹ בְצִיּוֹן׃
>   Salem became His abode; Zion, His den. ([Tehhilim 76.3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.76.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi))

In the same Posuk סוכה becomes masculine (סוכו) and מעון becomes feminine (מעונתו). In proper Hebrew it should read "ויהי בשלם סוכתו ומעונו בציון".

What's the reason for this switch?

Comment: I don't understand why you assert מעונה isn't a proper Hebrew word. מעונה shows up many times in Tanakh.

Answer (score -2):

This is explained by the [Malbim to this posuk in Tehillim](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.76.3?lang=he&with=Malbim&lang2=he) who says:

> **ויהי בשלום סוכו,** בירושלים ששם ישבו ההמון, שם היה סוכתו של ה', שהסוכה היא דירת עראי,
>
> **ומעונתו בציון,** בציון שם ישבו המלך והסנהדרין וכהני ה', שם היה מעונתו בקביעות כי שם היה מקדש ה' :

That the usage of *sukkah* in this connotation is the congregating place of the entire mob of people, both men and women. There is no order to it and all are mixed. That it why it refers to the whole city of *Shalom* (related to completeness, *shleimut* and also to Jerusalem).

But with the *Ma'on*, there is a specific order and arrangement. In that place are all the leaders (the King), and the Judges (the Sanhedrin), and those who administer to G-d (the Kohanim). They sit in a specific and desired order. It is referring to Har HaBayit.

This change to the feminine is relating to the concept that in terms of the system of the sephirot, the side pertaining to *Gevurah*, which is about judgement, discernment, division, etc., is associated with the specific, arranged places for everyone.

This same principle is emphasized in the *Zimone* of Grace after the meal for a wedding where the leader says:

> נברך אלקינו שהשמחה במעונו שאכלנו משלו

This usage of Ma'on is to emphasize that in this special meal, the men and women are careful to sit separately, in the proper, fixed order.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. I asked about grammatical gender, that's switched in this Posuk, not what the posuk is about. Meono is a correct form, but what and why is Meonato?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/39739)

Comment: @DonielF Not sure if you were addressing me. The question is kind of general. He asks why the posuk switches from masculine to feminine in regard to the usage of 'sukkah' and 'Ma'on'. My answer brings Malbim's differentiation of the 2 words in the context of the general kabbalistic concept of Gevurah (feminine) and Chesed (masculine). That same division is alluded to in 76:2. Both are from the one G-d. The downfall of the wicked (in this case Sennecheriv's soldiers) comes from this Gevurah aspect, which is feminine. That is what the change is indicating.

Comment: It seems you've misunderstood the question. It's not why the verse switched from the masculine סכו to the feminine מעונתו but rather why סוכה is conjugated with a atypically masculine suffix and why מעון is conjugated with an atypically feminine suffix.

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't misunderstand anything. The irregular usage is to point out the masculine & feminine concepts associated with these two different geographic locations. And that is precisely what my answer addresses.